# HDRI Not loading in Background

Tags: hdri

Newbie here. I am trying to load an HDRI I have downloaded from Poly Haven.

[image]

I was able to select the HDRI in *Shading* workspace by changing to *World*  and by using *Environment Texture* node. But this is where I encounter my problem (see image2).

I have checked the following in the attempt to fix it but still I cant see the background:

- I have checked if I was in render view
- I have toggled *Scene World*.
  [image]
- I went to *Object Data Properties > Film > Transparent*, I have toggle that on and off but still background is not showing.

[image]

- I have restarted blender
- I have moved my HDRI from different location (from USB, Blender folder in dive C:, and created another folder in PC Document)
- I uploaded a lower quality of the HDRI from 2k to 1k.

What else should I check to fix this problem?

Could this be also related to GPU? What could be my work around if this is the case?

Comment: The screenshot of the viewport is indicating that you are in orthgraphic mode, (top left hand corner of your third image) You need to be in Perspective mode to see the HDRI background. Num-pad key 5 toggles orthgraphic / perspective mode.

Comment: Thank you for this @3fingeredfrog .
I can now see the HDRI.